# Django form is not submitting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to save a modelform which has following fields

```
class DiaryText(models.Model):
   DiaryUser=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=False)
   DateCreated=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   DiaryBody=models.TextField(max_length=10000)
   DiaryHeading=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=False,null=True)
```

the corresponding modelform is :-

```
 class MakeADiaryForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model=DiaryText
        fields={'DiaryHeading','DiaryBody'}
        widgets={
            'DiaryHeading':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Title','class':'Headline'}),
            'DiaryBody':forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Start Writing','class':'BodyDiary'}),
        }
```

Corresponding View function is as follows:-

```
 def NewEntryView(request,slug):
    UserPresent=get_object_or_404(DiaryUser,Username=slug)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=MakeADiaryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            BlogEntry=form.save(commit=False)
            BlogEntry.DiaryUser=slug
            BlogEntry.save()
            return redirect('Display',**{'slug':BlogEntry.DiaryUer})
    else:
        form=MakeADiaryForm()
        return render(request,'Mobile/AddNewEntry.html',{'form':form,'slug':slug})
```

But the form is not saving the entered value and keeps on redirecting to same page. Display here is the name of another view while slug is the username.
can i also use a better keyword in place of slug like username. if yes, please specify how to

Comment: If `form.is_valid()` is false, the view can't do anything.  In this case, you need to provide a way to redisplay the form with error messages.

Comment: It is used in order to fill hidden fields of form and acceptable according to django documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common to see when you are new to Django forms. Here are some of the things that developers might often do which may result in this issue:

(1) **Not mentioning CSRF token:** Django uses CSRF tokens as a way to encrypt all the information you provide while sending it to the server. If you do not define it in your HTML template, depending on how you managed the submission, your page may either throw an error or simply reload.

(2) **Not declaring method of form:** This seems to be the issue in your case. Developers, when they are new with HTML, often forget to declare the HTTP method call that they shall be making with their form. Be sure to declare that you are making a POST method call inside the form tag, and it should work. Here's an example:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "">
```

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `return` is located in the wrong place (maybe just SO code pattern has done it) and you have to define **instance** in the form otherwise it will create the new one. For sure, this was your issue.:

```
def NewEntryView(request,slug):
    UserPresent=get_object_or_404(DiaryUser,Username=slug)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=MakeADiaryForm(request.POST, instance=UserPresent) # You have to define the instance you want to edit othervise it tries to create a new one. Most probobly this was your issue
        if form.is_valid():
            BlogEntry=form.save(commit=False)
            BlogEntry.DiaryUser=slug
            BlogEntry.save()
            return redirect('Display',**{'slug':BlogEntry.DiaryUer})
    else:
        form=MakeADiaryForm()

    return render(request,'Mobile/AddNewEntry.html',{'form':form,'slug':slug}) # here
```

Be sure your method name is `POST` in the form and you are not using any **action** since you are redirecting forms with `urls.py`. And another cause can be that the form is not passing is_valid() filter. Make sure you are inserting valid data.

**Tip:** in template use `{{ form.as_p }}` if this successfully loads that means your issue is with `is_valid()` filter. Alternatively, you can locate `print('valid')` right after if `is_valid():` to check it.