# How to apply condition on django boolean field?

Tags: django, django-forms, radio-button

I am working on an multi-vendor Django base E-commerce project. And I would like to implement a radio button base selection, like when a user add an item to cart I want him/her to choose (yes or no). Is this gift? when a user click on yes, I need to show a message input field where he/she can put custom message to print on item. There are multiple items in cart. Can Anyone guide me how to do this in django? Thank you in advance.

**Update** :
I have worked out javascript thing but form is not submitting in view post method. Checkout button does nothing on clicking.

```js
function hideShowGiftField(btnId, msgFieldId) {
            let btn = document.getElementById(btnId)
            let msgField = document.getElementById(msgFieldId)
            if (btn.value === 'yes') {
                msgField.type = 'text'
            } else if (btn.value === 'no') {
                msgField.type = 'hidden'
            }
        }

        function hideShowEngravingField(btnId, engravingFieldId) {
            let btn = document.getElementById(btnId)
            let engravingField = document.getElementById(engravingFieldId)
            if (btn.value === 'yes') {
                engravingField.type = 'text'
            } else if (btn.value === 'no') {
                engravingField.type = 'hidden'
            }
        }
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart_detail' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="">
            <h2 class="review-cart-desktop">Review Cart</h2>
            <hr>
            <h2 class="review-cart">Review Cart</h2>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <h4 class="mx-2 font-weight-bold">Item</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="row text-center header-names">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h6 class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Quantity</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h6 class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold">Price</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            {% for item in cart_items %}
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-8 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row d-flex">
                            <div class="book"><img src="{{ item.variant.first.product.main_image.url }}"
                                                   alt="{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}"
                                                   class="book-img">
                            </div>
                            <div class="my-auto flex-column d-flex pad-left">
                                <h6 class="mob-text-item"
                                    style="text-transform: capitalize">{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}</h6>
                                {% for variant in item.variant.all %}
                                    <p class="mob-text">{{ variant|capfirst }}</p>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {#                                            <p class="mob-text mob-text-custom"><a href="">View Custom Design</a></p>#}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 complete-row-input" style="margin-left: 150px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Is This is A Gift?</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <div class="d-flex" style="margin-left:15px ;">
                                        <label for="gift_yes_{{ item.id }}">Yes</label><input type="radio"
                                                                                              id="gift_yes_{{ item.id }}"
                                                                                              onchange="hideShowGiftField(this.id, 'custom-message-{{ item.id }}')"
                                                                                              name="{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}_gift"
                                                                                              value="yes"
                                                                                              class="mt-1 radio-size"
                                                                                              style="width: 30px;">
                                        <label for="gift_no_{{ item.id }}">No</label><input type="radio"
                                                                                            id="gift_no_{{ item.id }}"
                                                                                            onchange="hideShowGiftField(this.id, 'custom-message-{{ item.id }}')"
                                                                                            name="{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}_gift"
                                                                                            value="no"
                                                                                            class="mt-1 radio-size"
                                                                                            style="width: 30px;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="custom-message-{{ item.id }}" class="placeholder"
                                   placeholder="Custom Message"
                                   name="custom_message_for_{{ item.id }}"
                                   style="width: 100%;"/>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col-8">

                                    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Need Engraving?</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <div class="d-flex" style="margin-left:15px ;">
                                        <label for="engraving-yes">Yes</label><input type="radio"
                                                                                     id="engraving_yes_{{ item.id }}"
                                                                                     onchange="hideShowEngravingField(this.id, 'engraving-message-{{ item.id }}')"
                                                                                     name="{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}_engraving"
                                                                                     value="yes"
                                                                                     class="mt-1 radio-size"
                                                                                     style="width: 30px;">
                                        <label for="engraving-no">No</label><input type="radio"
                                                                                   id="engraving_no{{ item.id }}"
                                                                                   onchange="hideShowEngravingField(this.id, 'engraving-message-{{ item.id }}')"
                                                                                   name="{{ item.variant.first.product.name }}_engraving"
                                                                                   value="no"
                                                                                   class="mt-1 radio-size"
                                                                                   style="width: 30px;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="engraving-message-{{ item.id }}" class="placeholder"
                                   placeholder="Engraving Message"
                                   name="engraving_message_for_{{ item.id }}"
                                   style="width: 100%;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- </td> -->
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="row text-right">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mt-5">
                                <!-- <td> -->
                                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center counting">
                                    <p class="mb-2 mx-3 font-weight-bold" id="cnt1">{{ item.quantity }}</p>
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column plus-minus">
                                        <form action="" method="post">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <button onclick="increment('{% url 'item_increment' item.id %}')"
                                                    class="vsm-text plus">
                                                +
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                        <form action="" method="post">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <button onclick="increment('{% url 'item_decrement' item.id %}')"
                                                    class="vsm-text minus">
                                                -
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button-remove" align="center">
                                    <a href="{% url 'delete-cart-item' item.id %}" type="button"
                                       class="btn btn-danger remove-button mt-2">Remove
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mt-2" align="center">
                                <h6 class="mob-text-price">Rs {{ item.get_subtotal }}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row total-price-desktop">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="text-right total-price">Total : {{ total }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row total-price-mobile">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="total" align="left">Total</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="price" align="right">Rs :{{ total }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<hr>
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-4 offset-4">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {#                                <input type="submit" value="Checkout">#}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 50%">Checkout</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-checkout-bottom col-2 offset-2">
                <div style="float: right;">
                    <p><small>*Shipping Calculated on Next Step</small></p>
                    <p style="margin-top: -20px;"><small>*Select gift wrapping on Next Step</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Javascript. You should search how to manipulate html elements on the browser. When a user click to yes button you should create input html element on the browser. Javascipt is only one way to manupilate html tags on the browser.
I recommand you look at the DOM manipulation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

Also you should add message field on your product or order table. It should be nullable (Null=True), then if customer add message you can store this message on the message field.

Comment: There are multiple items in cart and their respective radio buttons with same name. Moreover, Custom message field is for multiple items. Like if there are 5 item in cart, there should be 5 input fields to display and post their data to database. How to tackle this scenario ?

Comment: If there are multiple items in the cart, you can loop them one by one on the template and you can put one radio button to click "yes or no" and one input for the gift message. This will create 5 radio buttons and 5 inputs, when items are looping you should add to them unique id like "radio_button_1", "radio_button_2"... Each numbers should add dynamicly and you can get this specific radio button like document.getElementById("radio_button_id"). If this radio button has yes message you can show specific input for specific radio button. For more informations I recommend you to check js DOM.

Comment: Hi @Turgay. I have managed to work the JavaScript thing. But I am having issue with posting form.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: Your logic looks correct, but you have a lot of form in your html, they may cause a problem. Check your browser console to see potential problems. From actions may be wrong, I suggest you check out these 2 questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809001/django-form-is-not-submitting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335459/django-form-not-being-submitted   Also you make sure that your form is valid in your views.py.

Comment: Yes, the issue was in forms in the mid of my main form. It's working now. Thank you @Turgay for your guidance.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for marking my answer as accepted. Also you can upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow so I can't upvote.